# How to fix Production Debugger native library is missing issue?

Tags: lucee, fusionreactor

I've one problem while access  view heap in memory tab.

[image]

- How to fix that ?

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: windows 7 ultimate. Service Pack : 1

Comment: Like it says, you need to add that string to the JVM JVM arguments, but given you are using CommandBox, I'm not sure how you would do that. Did you install FusionReactor from Forgebox? https://www.forgebox.io/view/commandbox-fusionreactor

Comment: Yes I'm refer above the link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution :**

- open Lucee service control in your System.
- Goto "Java" tab.
- Add agentPath in "Java options".

[image]

[image]